# Bought items in last 3 orders for each customer in tableau desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to find basket items (category, subcategory) in last 3 orders of each customer. So, in the end, I am hoping to cluster customers according to items or categories that were mostly bought in last 3 orders.I am stuck on finding a solution to calculate last 3 orders of each customer. I should use LOD expressions but which one and how?

I think using Fixed [Client id] is the starting point. Should I rank orders descending ( based on order date) and then filter it with "<=3".

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem a bit by giving some data/screenshots of data structure at least

Comment: Tell me one more thing, can any customer have more than 1 order on any given date?  What if a customer has >3 orders on last purchase date?  I mean how will you choose 3 orders from that range?

Answer (score 0):

Trying replicating your problem on <kbd>sample superstore</kbd> data.

- creating this calculation will give you `last order` for each customer

```
{fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} = [Order Date]
```

- creating this calculation will give you `last 2 orders`

```
{Fixed [Customer Name]:MAX(
If [Order Date] <> {fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} 
then [Order Date] END
)} = [Order Date]
OR 
{fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} = [Order Date]
```

- similarly creating this calculation will give you `last 3 orders`

```
{ FIXED [Customer Name] : max( IF 
{Fixed [Customer Name]:MAX(
If [Order Date] <> {fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} 
then [Order Date] END
)} <> [Order Date]
AND 
{fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} <> [Order Date]
THEN [Order Date] END)} = [Order Date]
OR
{Fixed [Customer Name]:MAX(
If [Order Date] <> {fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} 
then [Order Date] END
)} = [Order Date]
OR 
{fixed [Customer Name]: max([Order Date])} = [Order Date]
```

**only assumption is that there aren't more than 1 order on any given date.**

check it

[image]

Comment: If you can safely assume (or enforce) that an identifier like ORDER_ID monotonically increases over time (i.e. transactions with higher order ids completed later than transactions with lower order ids), then it is safer to use that identifier instead of a date to identify the latest transactions. That way you don’t have to be concerned about the case when multiple transactions share the same date. Most systems enforce that multiple transactions will not share the same order Id or other primary key - so take advantage of that.